# CakePHP Auth Component Blanks out Password

Tags: authentication, cakephp

I have the following code for my login view:

```
<?php 
    echo $session->flash('auth');
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'login'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

This generates the following HTML:

```
   <div id="authMessage" class="message">Login failed. Invalid username or password.</div>
   <form id="UserLoginForm" method="post" action="/control/users/login" accept-charset="utf-8">
      <div style="display: none;"><input name="_method" value="POST" type="hidden"></div>
      <div class="input text required">
         <label for="UserEmail">Email</label>
         <input name="data[User][email]" maxlength="255" value="" id="UserEmail" type="text">
      </div>
      <div class="input password">
         <label for="UserPassword">Password</label>
         <input name="data[User][password]" id="UserPassword" type="password">
      </div>
      <div class="submit"><input value="Login" type="submit"></div>
   </form>
```

App Controller:

```
    function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->fields = array (
            'username' => 'email',
            'password' => 'password'
        );
    }
```

When I attempt to log in I get an error that my password is incorrect. Here's a dump of $this->data:

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [email] => myemail@gmail.com
            [password] => 
        )

)
```

I found a few other similar questions on stackoverflow but none of them seem to have an answer. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Could you provide the HTML that the form helper is generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cakePHP Auth component will hash your password and try to match with the password in DB.
They are hashing the password with the **salt**.
If you are setHash to MD5 then
`MD5($password.$salt)` will be stored matched with the password in DB.

So plz make sure that you are storing the password is correct.

To enter some dummy data. i usually try to debug `$this->Auth->password($password)` Then i will copy the result and insert in DB.

If the password is wrong the Auth component will reset the password field internally.ie., why u get this result.

```
Array
(
    [User] => Array
        (
            [email] => myemail@gmail.com
            [password] => 
        )

)
```

This doesn't means your password is not available for checking with DB.

Happy Baking

Comment: Thank you very much! Your suggestion led me to realize my password field was set to CHAR(32) while I'm using SHA1 to hash. I coulda sworn I set it to 40 but I guess my mind slipped a bit. Thanks